# Jsf list of all facets

Tags: jsf, facet

Hi i know that i can use some facet variables in jsf like this:

```
<h:dataTable>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Item Description" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{item.description}" />
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

is there any documentation which lists all available facets?

i already looked at the sourcecode of

```
javax.faces.component.html.HtmlDataTable
```

but cant find any information of the facets here, where are the defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The facets are available by [`UIComponent#getFacets()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getFacets%28%29).

Do note that you need to obtain the particular one in your code snippet from `<h:column>` (`HtmlColumn`; `UIColumn`), not from `<h:dataTable>` (`HtmlDataTable`; `UIData`).

```
UIData table = getItSomehow();

for (UIComponent child : table.getChildren()) { // child == UIColumn.
    Map<String, UIComponent> facets = child.getFacets();
    UIComponent headerFacet = facets.get("header");
    // ...
}
```

By the way, looking in source code is funny, but looking in [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/html/HtmlDataTable.html) is the easiest first step. It also lists the methods inherited from superclasses which are otherwise not directly visible in the class' source. You'd immediately have noticed the self-explaining "getFacets()" method when searching for the word "facets" in the javadoc.